# Mouseover calls multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I am using 2 different scripts for a site of mine. One for modern browsers and one for IE.

Both use mouseover. How do I call both scripts? My code is:

```
onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip(); playSound(0);"
```

That does not work yet I am unsure how to call both.

Comment: Do you want to call both functions for every browser or do you want call a specific function for IE only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect the IE like this,

```
onmouseover="Play()"
```

In Play function detect the browser ( http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml ) and call relevant function,

```
function Play(){
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
       //your function for IE
    }else{
    // your function for other browsers
    }
}
```